# How to insert multiple commands into a batch file using a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am making a batch file (Let's call it Create.bat) that will create a batch file (Let's call it Created.bat) that will get multiple commands inserted in it.

One of the commands is as follows:

```
FOR /F %%x IN ('tasklist /NH /FI "IMAGENAME eq %TEST%"') DO IF %%%x == %TEST% goto ProgramON
```

But when I open Created.bat to edit after running Create.bat, I see the following code inserted:

```
FOR /F %%x == %TEST% goto ProgramON
```

Why does it cut out a portion of the code, and how can I fix it?

Comment: How are you inserting the commands into created.bat?

Comment: Using:
echo COMMAND >> Created.bat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some characters have to be escaped. Most of them (`&<>|`) with a caret (`^`). Percent signs are escaped with another percent sign:

```
>>created.bat echo DIR ^>nul
>>created.bat echo FOR /F %%%%x IN ('tasklist /NH /FI "IMAGENAME eq %%TEST%%"') DO IF %%%%x == %%TEST%% goto ProgramON
```