# was unexpected at this time

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to write a script that prints a variable. This is the code:

```
@echo off

set workspace=%CD%
set artifact_ids=online_deploy

for %%x in (%artifact_ids%) do (
    echo %workspace%
)
```

I get this error when I run the script from any folder inside ***C:\Program Files (x86)***: \ was unexpected at this time.

I am guessing there is a problem with the path name since I can run it succesfully from anywhere else except for Program Files **(x86)**.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Use the short name for the "Program Files (x86)" directory. Actually, it works on all directories. There might be other directories that contain spaces and special characters.

```
set "workspace=%CD%"
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%p IN ("%workspace%") DO (SET "workspace=%%~sp")
```

Comment: Need to double the percent symbols.

Comment: Thank you! I was able to run the script successfully!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, that the variable is expanded "too early", so the `)` from `Program Files (x86)` accidently closes the `for` loop.

There are at least three methods to safely handle this issue (besides using shortnames):

1) enclosing the string in quotes: `echo "%workspace%"`, `set "var=%workspace%"`
2) [escaping](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46025988/2152082) the closing paranthese
3) [Delayed expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082)

The following example shows all three methods:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "workspace=%ProgramFiles(x86)%"
set "artifact_ids=online_deploy"
for %%x in (%artifact_ids%) do (
    echo using quotes: "%workspace%"
    echo escaping:     %workspace:)=^)%
    echo delayed exp.: !workspace!
)
```

What method is the best, depends on your acutal code. There are pros and cons with all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, your code as posted does not demonstrate the problem. You're apparently substituting `echo` for the actual command you're using. Commendable, but in this case, misleading.

The problem is that the `)` is being interpreted as the closing parenthesis of the `do`. How to fix it will depend on your *actual* code.

Comment: What do you mean? Have you tried running the code yourself? The problem is reproducible with echo also...

Comment: @SabinAntohe, we have no idea what the current directory is when you run that batch file.

Comment: Yes  I've tried your code as posted. It produce a report `Program Files (x86` - no "was unexpected at this time" as reported.

Comment: @Squashman : you think maybe "I can run it succesfully from anywhere else except for Program Files (x86)" might be a clue???

Comment: Yeah, sorry. To reproduce this problem you must run the script from a folder inside Program Files (x86). For example: Program Files (x86)\Folder

Comment: So it's the same problem - I ran it from `program files (x86)`, but if it was say `program files (x86)\somewhere...` then the commands that `cmd` would see would be `echo program files (x86)\somewhere...` where the `do (` is matched by the `)` of `x(86)` and `cmd` wonders what to do with `\somewhere...`.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean now. Yes, my real code is much more complex. @lit Solution seems to work for the code I pasted here. Will see tomorrow if this work also on the real script. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, it will - but the same problem will occur with any directory containing `)` - and probably also any of the usual gang of `poison` characters (which have special meaning for batch) - especially `&`. As another approach, I'd try using subroutines - see `call /?` from the prompt.